# How to keep image width the same as window size

Tags: html, css

i am using an image slider for a website and need the image to stay the same size as the window depending on the width of the window.

i have this in CSS:

```
#slider {
    width:100%;
    height:306px;
    background:#fff url(loading.gif) no-repeat 50% 50%;
    position:relative;
    margin:0 auto;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px #999999;

#slider img {
    width:100%;
    height:306px;
    position:absolute;
    border:none;
    display:none;
}
```

and the HTML:

```
<div id="slider">
    <img src="images/image-slider-2.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
```

so the #slider is the div id and then #slider img for the image but its not keeping the image as 100%

any ideas on this?

Thanks

Comment: is #slider a direct child of body?

Answer (score 0):

The document body's width should be specified, too.

`html, body, #slider, #slider img { width: 100%; }`